# No sound on upgrade (18.04 -> 20.04) only have "dummy output"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 20.04

Prior to the upgrade my sound was working, now it's not. I only have one output "dummy output".

My computer has the snd_hda_intel sound card and I've tried all the steps outlined [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)

Any assistance would be appreciated, would like to avoid a reinstall.

System info, Thinkpad T460s, Kubuntu 20.04.

output of lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd                    90112  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

output of lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [17aa:2233]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Help_To_Debug_Intel_HDA

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1230363 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1230383.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

after lurking some other threads I was able to fix it by running

`sudo apt purge timidity-daemon`

The alsa reloads and config changes where of no use.

Comment: It worked! I still wonder why, though. What's wrong with Timidity-daemon?