# No sound after update to 20.04 "Dummy Output"

Tags: 20.04, sound, updates, pulseaudio

I lost sound after updating from 19.10 to 20.04.

My sound driver appears to have been replaced with dummy output, see below

[image]

No other output devices are available.  I have rebooted and the problem remains.

Comment: Can you change date output device by `pavucontrol`?

Comment: Does `dmesg` tell something about audio?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How do I use pavucontrol? And what should I be asking dmesg?

Comment: In terminal install it by `sudo apt install pavucontrol` and thereafter run it by the same name.

Comment: Try `dmesg | grep -iE 'sound|audio'` and `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -iE 'sound|audio'` and maybe you see something helpful in their output.

Comment: pavucontrol also shows that the only audio device I have is dummy output.

Comment: Can you run 
`lspci | grep -i audio` 
and reply back what you see?

Comment: Please, also edit the question to post the output of `inxi -A`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [20.04: internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/20-04-internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgradi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 "Dummy output" No sound card in use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242766/ubuntu-20-04-dummy-output-no-sound-card-in-use)

Comment: `Package 'timidity-daemon' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: `Package 'timidity' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: No, this is still a problem, and the answers suggested do not fix it. Reloading alsa does fix it temporarily, but the problem returns frequently.

Comment: I had a similar problem after doing an "apt update" on Ubuntu 20.04.  I found that just killing Pulseaudio fixed it when it respawned.  Not sure if this is a one off, but the comment may be useful to others.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul

Answer (score 8):

I would first suggest rebuilding new **pulseaudio** configuration for your user account. This might, in most cases, fix the problem or at least rule out issues related to pulseaudio configuration.

Old `pulseaudio` configuration files can sometimes conflict with newer versions of `pulseaudio` after package or system upgrades. **To fix this**, please follow the steps below:

- Back up `~/.config/pulse/` configuration directory to `~/.config/pulse_old/` by running the following command in the terminal:

  ```
  mv  ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse_old/
  ```
- After that, please reboot your system to build new `pulseaudio` configuration files. A new `~/.config/pulse/` directory will be created automatically.
- Test your audio now.

If, somehow, **after applying this fix** you decide to **go back to the previous state before applying the fix**, please follow the steps below:

1. Run the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   rm -r  ~/.config/pulse/
   ```
2. Run the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   mv  ~/.config/pulse_old/ ~/.config/pulse/
   ```
3. Reboot your system.

However, **if all is okay and the problem is fixed**, you can remove the backed up old configuration directory `~/.config/pulse_old/` to free space ( if you wish ) by running the following command in the terminal:

```
rm -r  ~/.config/pulse_old/
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Deleting the folder `~/.config/pulse/` and restarting the system worked.

Comment: This fixed my sound problem with 22.04. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

I have found a similar problem in a different thread, [you might want to try this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231426/no-sound-on-upgrade-18-04-20-04-only-have-dummy-output):

It also happened to me a couple of times, though I can't remember if rebooting used to solve my problem... Anyway I found the following line to be helpful:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

I can't find the original thread with the solution and explanation, but it's practically shutting/killing the deamon and forcing alsa to reload.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, you can follow steps mentioned in the answer of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1509312/sound-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-linux-5-4-intel-hd-audio/1509313#1509313). If the link doesn't work just do this.

Open your terminal and after that:

1. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to the end of it. (ex: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`")
3. run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
4. reboot your system

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a mixed several threads: this thread and [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound), [another one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242766/ubuntu-20-04-dummy-output-no-sound-card-in-use) and [latest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgrading-from):

```
# Edit backlist kernel:
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" >> /etc/modprobe.d/backlist.conf

# Edit alsa options
echo "snd-hda-intel model=generic" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

# Edit /etc/default/grub    
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"

# Reinstall alsa-base and pulseaudio    
apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
alsa force-reload

# Purge timidity
apt purge timidity-daemon

# Some trick: https://askubuntu.com/a/1249071/756376
sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/*
```