# sound and microphone not working after software update in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FuZu.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koxRC.png)

I have tried many ways but not able to get the sound and the microphone back

first, it showed dummy output so I ran [this link commands](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html#:%7E:text=Hopefully%20your%20sound%20now%20works,d%2Falsa%2Dbase.) and rebooted my system but it showed the content in the attached photos.

and also when were I use `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` there is no output.

please advise something so that it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound after update to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237372/no-sound-after-update-to-20-04)