# Ubuntu 21.10 Only Plays Audio Only Through Monitors

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 and the audio pipes through only the monitor. I have tried playing around in pavucontrol and this is what I see

[image]

Here is the output from the terminal

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa3510000 irq 142
 1 [C920           ]: USB-Audio - HD Pro Webcam C920
                      HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-0000:00:14.0-6, high speed
 2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xa3080000 irq 17
 3 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Audio Device
                      USB PnP Audio Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-9, full speed
```

Any suggestions how to set the audio to come from line out. Even when I manually select Line Out from the system settings, audio only comes via the monitor.

Comment: I suggest trying [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301214) first.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much