# How can I change dummy ouput mode audio on linux (Ubuntu 20) to the default mode? (I can't hear anything!)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, thinkpad, audio-sync

I want change the audio mode from dummy output mode to the default mode, I can't hear anything in dummy mode and I don't know why it's happened, I can't hear anything! so please help me! can I change it with pulseaudio or sth like that?

Comment: Related: [No sound after update to 20.04 "Dummy Output"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1237372/968501)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound after update to 20.04 "Dummy Output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237372/no-sound-after-update-to-20-04-dummy-output)

Comment: @Pilot6 I did whatever I could to do! That means all the answers to all the comments and ...! but It didn't work! I tested my speakers, they are working well! but I have really no idea about it!!!! even I'm changing the output on pulseaudio and volume and everything! speakers are unavailable on pulseaudio!!!!!          THE LIFE IS BEAUTIFUL !

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? There is no "Ubuntu 20"? Also we don't know your audio hardware. So it is impossible to help.

Comment: @Pilot6 I got this error hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5  with this command "dmesg"!! My ubuntu version is 20.04!!