# Dummy Output / No Sound on IPASON MaxBook P1X

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a IPASON MaxBook P1X a couple weeks ago, and I've never been able to get sound to work on it.

- Going into settings, the only available output available is Dummy Output.
- In alsamixer, the card is "sof-hda-dsp", and the chip is "Intel Geminilake HDMI"
- Also, alsamixer has six bars (S/PDIF, S/PDIF 1, S/PDIF 2, PGA2.0 2 Master, PGA3.0 3 Master, and PGA4.0 4 Master). Only the last three can be turned up or down, and they are already 100%. None of them are muted
- inxi -Axxx yields

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl bus-ID: 00:0e.0 chip-ID: 8086:3198
    class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-41-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

- The configuration tab in pavucontrol says only "No cards available for configuration"
- lspci -v yeilds (much more than this, but this is what i assume is important. I can send the full result if needed)

```
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device 02f3:f000
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at a1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci_intel_apl
```

- pacmd list-cards yields 0 card(s) available.
- pacmd list-sinks yields

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 14
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

I have tried using Bluetooth headphones to no avail. Using headphones with a cord also doesn't work

That is all I could think to give, if you need anything else I can get it. Any help is appreciated.

**-- Edit --**

I have tried the methods listed in [No sound after update to 20.04
Dummy Output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237372/no-sound-after-update-to-20-04-dummy-output)

Now, instead of Dummy Output I get "HDMI / DisplayPort - Built In Audio". alsa-mixer now only has one bar, which cannot be moved up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound after update to 20.04 "Dummy Output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237372/no-sound-after-update-to-20-04-dummy-output)

Comment: @Raffa I tried all the methods mentioned in that thread. Audio still doesn't work, however, instead of Dummy Output I get "HDMI / DisplayPort - Built In Audio". alsa-mixer now only has one bar, which cannot be moved up