# Seeing Dummy Output for sound on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04

My newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't recognize the Creative Pebble V3 speakers. Under Settings > Sound > Output > Output Device it shows "Dummy Output" as the only option. I have tried restarting PulseAudio with `pulseaudio -k` and it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound after update to 20.04 "Dummy Output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237372/no-sound-after-update-to-20-04-dummy-output)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - tried various alsa and other debug options but to no avail.  Saw that in one of the ubuntu updates, my kernel used 5.15....-oracle.  This also messed up my display drivers (had to reinstall NVIDIA drivers and download appropriate kernel source for the kernel).

Any way, updated the kernel to 5.19.17 and now sound card is detected and working.  There is a continuous light cracking noise in the background though!