# No sound on recent installation of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the sound isn't working in my built in speakers. Firstly it started by displaying "Dummy Output" in the system and after a couple of troubleshooting I read it now displays "HDMI output" although the laptop doesn't have it. I tried lscpi and it seems that the speakers are recognized. In ALSA the first column doesn't work. I tried pulse sound is as system. Kernel version is **5.15.0-60-generic**

EDIT Heres the output for **sudo lshw -C sound**

```
*-usb:2                   
       description: Video
       product: HD Camera: HD Camera
       vendor: Azurewave
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       logical name: input12
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
       version: 21.03
       serial: 0001
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6001120000-6001123fff memory:6001000000-60010fffff
```

Comment: Please add the output of the following command to your post: `sudo lshw -C sound`

Comment: I am sorry we just got into a funeral, I'll do it when I get home.

Comment: Sorry for your loss. No worries, it can wait.

Comment: There is no kernel 5.15  ig.

Comment: @David `ig` is for I guess, I guess ;-)

Comment: A real kernel number may be more help.

Comment: @David i just edited it hope it clears things up

Comment: @popey I just ran it, hope it clears things out

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1237372

Answer (score 0):

Same here for 5.19.0-35-generic kernel.

I'm using 5.19.0-32-generic now as workaround.

You can use Mainline tool ([installation guide](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/2-utilities-to-install-latest-kernel-in.html)) to manage kernel versions.
Or just figure out if older kernel version you used to have beore update exists in Grub (pre boot screen, Advanced boot settings) and works for your case.